# Angular 2 keep selected value after rebinding array to select

Tags: arrays, angular

I would like to keep the value in a select when the array of items is 'reloaded', when the original selected item is in the new array, otherwise I want it to select the default option (empty value).

I created a plunker [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/KmGJCi?p=preview)

In the example you can see the selected car is still the car you selected even when you refresh the list. Now I need to add some code to reselect the selected car in the select.

```
<select [ngModel]="selectedCar || ''" (ngModelChange)="setSelectedCar($event)">
  <option value="">--select a car--</option>
  <option *ngFor="let car of cars" [ngValue]="car">{{ car.brand }} - {{ car.model }}</option>
</select>

<br>
<br>

<label>Selected car:</label> <span *ngIf="selectedCar">{{ selectedCar.brand }} - {{ selectedCar.model }}</span> <span *ngIf="!selectedCar">none selected</span>
```

The reason I use one-way binding and use ngModelChange is to be able to have the default (--select a car--) functionality.

But when I refresh the list I get an empty selected value in the select (edit: in chrome).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you bind your dropdown to an object. When you change the object list the selected value (object) is no longer in the list and can therefore not be selected again. What you'll need to do is after the selected list changed, set the selectedCar again to the appropriate new object that is equivalent to the previously selected object.

See this edited plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/HKpBLx?p=preview

Note how in the `src/select-widget.ts file` I've added the following block:

```
ngOnChanges() {
   if (this.selectedCar) {
       this.selectedCar = this.cars.find(i => i.brand === this.selectedCar.brand 
           && i.model === this.selectedCar.model);
   }
}
```

You'd probably rather use something like an ID to find the right car again, but this should help you get on the way.

Comment: Yep, that was easy, how didn't i think of that myself :-)

Comment: No problem, glad to have been of help. Would you mind upvoting the answer for me (and future visitors)